# RxJs good tutorials

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to learn ReactiveX. I have spent almost a whole day and I am not able to understand it properly. I tried to look the official documentation but is is very difficult to understand. Something like this:

"Rx.Observable.prototype.flatMapLatest(selector, [thisArg])

Projects each element of an observable sequence into a new sequence of observable sequences by incorporating the element's index and then transforms an observable sequence of observable sequences into an observable sequence producing values only from the most recent observable sequence."

How a new person is able to understand it. So if someone knows the good resource then please mention

Comment: This question is off-topic, but... to help out... https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 https://egghead.io/technologies/rx are just a few resources

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As a commenter has said, Brian Troncone's page is a good place: https://www.learnrxjs.io/.

The reality is that learning Rx is not a snap. The hard part isn't learning the library, the operators, etc. Rx requires at least a little bit of investment in thinking differently, at least for most people (myself included).

The best way to start understanding it is to play with it. For RxJS, the interactive examples in [rx-book](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/index.html) are a great place to start. They use jsbin, so you can run the sample code to see the output, then tweak the code to see what difference it makes.

From a .Net angle, playing with Linqpad is the best way to start getting a feel for how Rx works.

Ultimately you'll need to combine different aspects of learning:

- Some theory reading
- Some practical examples (which is where rx-book is useful)
- Some practical application to a demo or real system of your own

I have a list of helpful resources that I've compiled [here](https://blog.niallconnaughton.com/2015/08/12/rx-learning-resources/). But there is so much being put out there, especially on rxjs, that it's hard to keep up.

What's not common is true examples of real world usage of Rx. Partly this is because Rx is typically applied to larger scale problems, so it's not easy to just fabricate a good use case to make a demo from.

[ReactiveTrader](https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/ReactiveTraderCloud) is one example of a large scale demonstration of applying Rx. It's a good example of an app making heavy use of Rx to build a complex web app that deals with streaming data and UI events.

I've also given a talk on how to apply Rx to tweet streams to analyze the data. This is oriented around real-time manipulation, aggregation and filtering of streaming data. There's a full video of the talk, plus articles discussing the approach and results [here](https://blog.niallconnaughton.com/2016/10/25/ndc-sydney-talk/).

Ultimately it will take you time to learn Rx, but it will be worth the effort if you follow through.

Comment: I have finally finished my first release of my quarantine project! A game to learn RxJS. Please share and have fun playing it... https://www.rxjs-fruits.com

Comment: Where do you see interactive examples in rx-book? This are just code listenings

Answer (score 10):

The best way to learn RxJs to play with it by going through the [api reference](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/identifiers.html). 
Besides that you can go through the following resources:

1. Video courses on [Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/technologies/rx)
2. Awesome explanation: [The introduction to Reactive Programming
   you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754)
3. [Hot vs Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) ( Also All [Ben Lesh Articles](https://medium.com/@benlesh) on Medium)
4. Tutorials on youtube like : [Adding Even More Fun to Functional
   Programming With RXJS - Ryan Anklam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EExNfm0gt4)
5. Explanatory tutorial with example on
   https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-reactive-programming-and-rxjs/