# Canceling all async functions when navigation changes in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When this component loads, the `startSync` function starts. However, I also have an `exit` function that navigates to a login screen if pressed during any of this.

What happens though is, if I press the exit button, it brings me back to the login page. However, the async function is still running so when it finishes it will then navigate me to the `Identification` screen.

I was wondering if there is a way to cancel all Async function's so that nothing is running in the background after the exit button is pushed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, Button, StatusBar, Text, StyleSheet, View, } from 'react-native';
import * as pouchDB_helper from '../utils/pouchdb';

type Props = {};
export default class SyncScreen extends Component<Props> {

  startSync = async () => {

    pouchDB_helper.sync().then((response) => {

      AsyncStorage.setItem('initial_sync', 'true');

      //navigate to the identification page
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Identification');

    }, (error) => { Alert.alert("Error", "Syncing failed. Please try again."); });

  }

  exit = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startSync();
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Syncing Settings',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText} onPress={this.exit}>Exit</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Promises can't be cancelled. You should look into using observables, as one of their advantages is the ability to be cancelled by unsubscribing to the event stream.

Comment: @Mikkel do you have any links for reference that I could research?

Comment: You can also use Futures instead of promises, as they are cancellable https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture

Comment: Try these https://www.learnrxjs.io/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782357/rxjs-good-tutorials https://medium.com/@mutebg/learn-rxjs-by-examples-c56bf481bec2 it will take some time to get your head around it, but it's very cool once you do